# Return information to Card

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working on a card add-on, inside this card i am trying to call a Google admin sdk API.
(GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/groupKey) The value of groupKey can be the group's email address, group alias, or the unique group ID i use:
`AdminDirectory.Groups.Get(groupId)`

I can insert a groupKey via text input, as test it logs to the console.log.
Now my problem is, how can i return the values back to the card as text or something?

````
function myFunction(e) {
    // Input from user.
    var textInput = e.formInput.text_input;
    const groups = myGroupsM.GroupsM();
    // Export log on input from user "This works fine to console log"
    console.log(groups.Groups.get(textInput));

    // I tried below as a test to display text on card. Gives a error!
    // Is it because it returns wrapped information? like this -> {infoyouget: []}
    // Or do you need to give a parameter that you want to display?
    var testText = CardService.newTextParagraph()
    .setText(groups.Groups.get(text));
    
    var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
    var cardSection = CardService.newCardSection().setHeader('Test Header')
    .addWidget(testText);
    // Found a thread on stackoverflow but it was about a clickable image. They suggested to use
    // brackets in the return as below.
    return [card.addSection(cardSection).build()];
} ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `AdminDirectory.Groups.get(groupId)` returns  you an object of the type
  `{kind=XXX, email=YYY, nonEditableAliases=[ZZZ]...}`
- You can access individual elements of this reponse as a string, e.g.:
  `AdminDirectory.Groups.get(groupId).email`
- If you want to return to your card the whole response as a string, you can simply convert the object to a string, e.g. with `AdminDirectory.Groups.get(groupId).toString()`

Comment: Thanks for your reply this helped me out. Just started a new journey as Junior Dev and coding in Google Apps Script. I thought too difficult.